# C++ option/long option implementation

Tags: c++, linux, parsing

I am working on a parser for meta programming language using C++ on Linux platform. Right now, I need to implement option/long option for the parser to provide some additional features. Basically, if the user pass in some additional option, the parser needs to store statistics while parsing the text files.

I can think of two ways to implement it. One way is to user global to store options entered by users. Another way is to create a singleton class to store options. So I would like to know if there is any other way to implement it. What is the best/most recommended way of implementing it? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

K.Hein

Comment: Since the configuration elements must be global to the environment of the parser anyway, either will work. I would suggest that until you have your feature-set for options that are configurable you maintain a simple id-value container. Once you *know* what options will be exposed for certain, you can replace it with something speedier) Keep it simple and open-ended. until then

Comment: You can see implementation in boost::program_options.

Answer (score 2):

Both globals and singleton would make unit testing of your parser a pain. To unit test how your parser behaves with different options, your test would need to modify globals. There are at least two problems with such approach: There is no clear association between globals and your class. Other than examining the implementation, the reader can't tell which globals are used inside your class and how they affect the behavior. Such globals can't be const (because they are set in main). So you loose the ability to communicate and enforce that once parser is created the value of options can't be changed.

Classic singleton is even worse than globals, because it gives you no way to replace the implementation and usually completely impedes testing.

A nice approach would be to inject a const object that stores options to the parser constructor. But don't put command line parsing logic in this object, otherwise you won't be able to conveniently use the object in tests.

Comment: Hi Jan, could you elaborate a bit more on injection of a const object? Or it would be great if you could point out some reference tutorial/examples to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jan's answer, you would have a function like:

```
bool my_parser(const parser_options &options);
```

The `parser_options` type can be a simple structure, e.g.:

```
struct parser_options
{
    FILE *source_file;
    bool warnings_as_errors;
    std::shared_ptr<error_handler> eh;
    ...
};
```

The `error_handler` can be defined like this:

```
struct error_handler
{
    virtual void error(int code, const char *message) = 0;
    virtual void warning(int code, const char *message) = 0;
    virtual ~error_handler() {}
};
```

The program would then do something like:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv)
{
    parser_options options;
    // process argc/argv options here, adding them to options, e.g.:
    //     case WARN_AS_ERROR: options.warnings_as_errors = true; break;
    return my_parser(options, &error) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_FAILURE;
}
```

This allows you to write tests that call `my_parser` directly, setting up `parser_options` independently of the command line handling and allows for a different `error_handler` to be specified (e.g. one that formats the information in a form that is machine readable).

NOTE: This is not meant to be a perfect design of a parser, it is just an example of how something like this can be designed.

NOTE: This design is not strictly necessary for testing, providing that the application can be configured to control the pipeline (e.g. no optimization, printing internal AST, internal representation, assembly code, preprocessor output). However, the design is more flexible as it allows different programs to use it without calling the command line program directly (GUI application/IDE, static analysis tools, etc.).

Comment: There are quite a number of classes involves in the parser application. So with this approach, I have to pass options to every classes explicitly in the application? This will require some effort to refactor the classes.

Comment: You could pass the options to every class in the application, or you can only pass what you need (e.g. the code generation classes do not need parsing options). You could use bitflags for lots of bool options. Designing a good architecture is complex. You will likely go through several iterations to get it right. Start on the leaf classes, add tests for them and build upward. It will take time, but will be worth it. You should really be iteratively improving the design, focusing on specific areas, using your experience from what you have written, what does not quite work or is hard to update.